# Javascript - Custom arrays not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, prototype

Please check the code below -

```
custom_array.push(...) is working
but
custom_array[i] = "n"
```

is not working.

There are a couple more things which i am not sure why it is not working. Please note the comments with "?" which is not working. Please refer fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vc0bbm3d/

Comment: you can't inherit from `Array` in javascript

Comment: suppose i want a custom_array which is exactly like an array, with some extra functions in it. then?

Comment: @Teemu - Please check the comment, that is what i meant by not working.

Comment: Well, I didn't take a look at the fiddle. Anyway, [something to read](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

Comment: @nikhilrao if you want to extend the default array object's functionality, it's better to create an abstraction layer over the array object than to extend the prototype itself.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan - Can you please create a fiddle with your approach. i dont know what is meant by an abstraction layer over the array object, and how to do it as well

Comment: @nikhilrao That's explained in the article I've linked above.

Comment: For goodness' sake, don't send people to a jsfiddle and make them sit through five `alert()`s.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that setting items using bracket syntax doesn't work for your object inheriting an array, is that it's not actually an array.

An array has special code for handling property assignment (which is what you do with the bracket syntax) when the property name is an integer. If the index is outside the current length, the `length` property is adjusted.

When you assign a value to a property in your object, there is no special code to handle the length. The property is just assigned as usual, and the length is never adjusted. As the object already has code for handling what's happening when you use the bracket syntax, the array that it inherts never comes into play.

For the bracket syntax to work in that way, the object has to be an actual array.

Comment: ... or an host object.

Comment: @guffa - If i wanted the bracket syntax to work like an ordinary array, then how to do it

Comment: @nikhilrao: The article that Teemu linked to has a solution that works for an object, but it's not supported in all browsers, for example IE8 and earlier. For full support you have to use an actual array.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ar[3] = 2;
ar.length =4
```

That way it knows you have  added something.

Comment: Why should i explicitly set the length? shouldn't it behave like an array and automatically set the length

Comment: because "arrays" are built on associative arrays.  meanings you can do  blah[1]=  oor  blah['bsf']=   and associate anything.  But normal ol arrays use length to know that associations 0 -> length-1  are a "array"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I mean when I say create a layer around the default array object to extend functionality:

```
var SuperArray = function(){
  this.arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
};
//abstraction of default array functionality
SuperArray.prototype.set = function(index, value){
  this.arr[index] = value;

  return this;
};

SuperArray.prototype.unset = function(index){
  this.arr.splice(index, 1);

  return this;
};
//extension of default array functionality
SuperArray.prototype.consoleList = function(){
  var arr = this.arr;
  for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
  };

  return this;
};

var extArr = new SuperArray(1,2,3);

extArr.set(2, 25); //does array[2] = 25;
extArr.unset(1);   //removes array[1]
extArr.consoleList();//console.logs all items in array

extArr.set(2, 25).unset(1).consoleList();//same thing
```

this simple object accepts arguments and sets them directly into an array, which we then manipulate how we wish. You can then add any utility functions that you need, check for existing array functionality, etc.